# Target multiple specific elements that appear within a div of a certain class

Tags: css

I am sure this question has been asked before, but I have searched for awhile an can't find the answer-- so here goes:

lets say I have a div of a certain class,  in this case we can call it .nyg-section-darkblue, and I want any H tag element to appear a certain color when it is nested in a div of this class, for example: this color:#19A5FF;

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this with CSS?

I have tried this:

```
.nyg-section-darkblue h6,h3,h4 {color:#19A5FF;}
```

but that appears to select H elements universally, and not just ones that are nested in "nyg-section-darkblue" class elements.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
 <style>
  /*css*/
   .nyg-section-darkblue h6,h3,h4 {color:#19A5FF !important;}
  </style>


 <!-- html-->

 <div class="nyg-section-darkblue">

<h3>I want this to be color #19A5FF</h3>
<h4>I want this to be color #19A5FF</h4>
<h6>I want this to be color #19A5FF</h6>



</div>


<div class="nyg-section-white">

<h3>I dont want this to be #19A5FF</h3>
<h4>I dont want this to be #19A5FF</h4>
<h6>I dont want this to be #19A5FF</h6>



</div>
```

Comment: can you share your HTML code?

Comment: i put in a redacted example of my code

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
.nyg-section-darkblue h6, .nyg-section-darkblue h3, .nyg-section-darkblue h4 { ....
```

Comment: Thanks- I considered doing that,  but it seemed really inefficient to have to enter the class for each H element--- theres gotta be a better way

Comment: If you want all the h elements under that class to have that color, you have to repeat the class name! Or you can define a class .color and add that class to your h elem in the html...

Comment: Why you think this is an inefficient way? H1, h2, h4 have only a similar name, but they are different tags, like label, a etc... If you want you can wrap the h* element in a common tag (hgroup for example), and in your css .class-black hgroup { color: black }

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS selector `>` to select children elements.  You can select the children of `.nyg-section-darkblue` like this: `nyg-section-darkblue > a`.

Example follows:

```css
.nyg-section-darkblue > a {
  color: #19A5FF;
}

a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nyg-section-darkblue">

  <a href="alink.html">Home</a>
  <a href="alink.html">About</a>
  <a href="alink.html">Products</a>
  <a href="alink.html">Contact</a>

</div>

<a href="alink.html">Home</a>
<a href="alink.html">About</a>
<a href="alink.html">Products</a>
<a href="alink.html">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Yes, this answer selects `<anchor>` elements as an example of what you can do with the `>` selector.  You can replace whatever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

.nyg-section-darkblue h6,h3,h4 {color:#19A5FF;}

is same as

```
.nyg-section-darkblue h6 {color:#19A5FF;}
h3 {color:#19A5FF;}
h4 {color:#19A5FF;}
```

you have to target that specific header tags that are inside a specific div , you can use the '>' selector

here is a code example

```css
.asd{
    font-size:13px;
    color:green;
}
h2{
    font-weight:bold;
}
h4{
    font-family:cursive;
}
.asd > h2{
    color:red;
    font-size:18px;
}
.asd h4{
  color:cyan;
 }
```

```html
<div class="asd">
    <h3>hello</h3>
    <p>are you</p>
    <h2> reading this</h2>
    <div id="inner">
        <h4> ahaa</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the '>' selector targets the h2 and h3 elements who are the direct children of the parent class. here is a link to css selectors from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

hope this helps